# How to change the background of many images when user entered a text in EditText in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have a program that has 10 images. I want to change the background of each image when the user enters valid text in editText. So basically if user enters valid text in the editText it will change the first image (image 1). If the user enters text again in editText it should change image 2 etc. until image 10.

I have tried to create a list of images and retrieve every element in the image.

I don't know if my logic is wrong

The images are stamp1, stamp2, stamp3, stamp4 ....stamp12

```
final String Entercode = codeNumber.getEditableText().toString().trim();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Entercode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (Entercode.equals("sweet")){


     for (int i = 0; i < stampImageList.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = stampImageList.get(i);
            stampImageList = new ArrayList();
            stampImageList.add(stamp1);
            stampImageList.add(stamp2);
            stampImageList.add(stamp3);
            stampImageList.add(stamp4);
            stampImageList.add(stamp5);
            stampImageList.add(stamp6);
            stampImageList.add(stamp7);
            stampImageList.add(stamp8);
            stampImageList.add(stamp9);
            stampImageList.add(stamp10);
            stampImageList.add(stamp11);
            stampImageList.add(stamp12);

            if (obj == stampImageList.get(2)) {
                // stamp4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.earned_stamp);
                stamp3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.earned_stamp);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                builder.setMessage("Stamp Earned");

            } else if (obj == stampImageList.get(3)) {
                stamp5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.earned_stamp);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                builder.setMessage("Stamp Earned");
            }


        }

            } else{
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                alert.setTitle("Validation results");
                alert.setMessage("validation failed");

            }
```

Comment: use textwatcher

Comment: What result are you getting right now with current code?

Comment: By using my current code it crashes. the application. The problem i have is not on the editText valid value should be the same. I want to be able to change one image after another when I enter the code in edit text. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextWatcher to EditText.In afterchange method you compare with values.

```
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "Set text xyz");
     et.setText("xyz");

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int  after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "afterTextChanged:\t" +s.toString());//Compare here with stamp1 or like that

     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

@steve, here I have prepared a code for 10 Drawable Images in your project.

```
    public class Pictures_Activity_stack extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  String TAG= "Pictures_Activity---";
    private ImageView picture;
    private EditText text;
    private Button validate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pictures_stack);

        picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture); //imageview where your picture changes
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);//edittext where you input text
        validate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);//button to validate the text and change picture accordingly

//        array to store your drawable images
        final int pictures[] = {
                R.drawable.firstimage,
                R.drawable.secondimage,
                R.drawable.p3,
                R.drawable.p4,
                R.drawable.p5,
                R.drawable.p6,
                R.drawable.p7,
                R.drawable.p8,
                R.drawable.p9,
                R.drawable.p10
        };

        // click the button to set the image
        validate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String input = text.getText().toString(); //input from edittext
                if (input.equals("first")) {
                    picture.setImageResource(pictures[0]); //set first image in array if input=first 
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),input,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
                else if (input.equals("second")) {
                    picture.setImageResource(pictures[1]);//set first image in array if input=secind 
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),input,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
//                else if (input.equals("third")) {
//                             // and so on for other string values...
                //              .................................
//                }

                else
                {
//                    if your input does not matches any string do this
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"NO MATCHED STRING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code set images according to input in edit Text, when button is clicked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Effort. Sir. The code is good but not very helpful. What i did not mention to you earlier is: The 10 images are same in drawable resources. So all images value in drawable is R.drawable.image they just have different id. So i want by calling the id of the image i could just change its background when i enter valid data in EditText. That why i used a list to take image as object add the image and get the image index in the list then change the background of the image. I dont know if im clear enough.

Comment: I really want to help you out, but still I am not clear with the question. You can share the _screenshot_ of your activity. I can see you are trying to create a _alert_ _dialog_ when a user user enters a _code_ and display an image(_stamp_) respective to each _code_.